# Extracting the value from webpage using simple html dom

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, file-get-contents

I have searched over net and found the way to extract data using simple html dom but it's giving me the following error:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://www.flipkart.com/moto-g-2nd-gen/p/itme6g3wferghmv3):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
>   in C:\Users\Abhishek\Desktop\editor\request\simple_html_dom.php on
>   line 75
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in
>   C:\Users\Abhishek\Desktop\editor\request\main.php on line 9

My designed php code for it is:

```
<?php 

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.flipkart.com/moto-g-2nd-gen/p/itme6g3wferghmv3');


foreach($html->find('span.selling-price.omniture-field') as $e)
    echo $e->outertext . '<br>';

?>
```

I an new in this programming and don't have enough knowledge but is there any mistake in my program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server is probably rejecting your request based on the User-Agent, try using curl to get the page html, i.e.

```
<?php
$url="http://www.flipkart.com/moto-g-2nd-gen/p/itme6g3wferghmv3";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
$pagebody=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html($pagebody);

foreach($html->find('.selling-price') as $e)
    echo $e->outertext . '<br>';
```

---

## Output:

Rs. 10,999

---

## Note:

I can confirm the server is rejecting your request based on the User-Agent.

Comment: still its not returning the price.

Comment: I've update my answer, If it helped you, please consider vote 1+ and accepting it as the correct answer by clicking the check mark in the middle of the vote arrows, tks !

Answer (score 4):

Make sure [fopen wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) are enabled to do this.. From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled.

As a result of this being disabled `file_get_contents()` returns `false` which causes your second error.